# Android rename file successful but file is deleted

Tags: android, file-rename

I want rename file and when use bellow code and rename file successful but after I don't see that file on my phone and the file is deleted. I requested 2 permissions READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE and WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE successful

My code to get all image in device and rename function

```
MainActivity{
   getAllImages()
   btn_rename.setOnClickListener{
      var old_file=listImageFile.get(pos_selected)
      var new_file=File(old_file.parent,new_name)
      var check:Boolean=old_file.renameTo(new_file)
      if(check){
         // check return true 
      }
   }
}
 fun getAllImages() {
        listImageFile= arrayListOf()
        val allImages = arrayListOf<Uri>()
        val imageProjection = arrayOf(
            MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA,
        )

        val cursor = requireActivity().contentResolver.query(
            MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
            imageProjection,
            null,
            null
        )
        cursor.use {
            if (cursor != null) {
                val data = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA)
                while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                    var path = cursor.getString(data)
                    var file=File(path)
                    if(file.exists()){
                        listImageFile.add(
                            FileData(
                                file,
                                false
                            )
                        )
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Whenever you create/rename/delete file, you must refresh the system files.**

Try this below solution after rename the file:

```
btn_rename.setOnClickListener{
  var old_file=listImageFile.get(pos_selected)
  var new_file=File(old_file.parent,new_name)
  var check:Boolean=old_file.renameTo(new_file)
  if(check){
     // check return true 
     MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(context, arrayOf(old_file.absolutePath),null,null)
     MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(context, arrayOf(new_file.absolutePath),null,null)
  }
```

}